# Free trial devexpress give all opportunities devexpress?

Tags: devexpress

There is a unified component installer on the official devexpress website **Unified Component Installer (includes .NET | ASP.NET Core | JavaScript)** - free trial version. I'm interesting if all devexpress functionality is available in the unified components installer?

I didn't find an answer to my question on the official website.

Answer (score 0):

yes, all functionality is available in the unified components installer